# Accepted collection for working with Excel data

Tags: c#, .net, types, linq-to-entities

I have a bunch of data that I'm pulling into my application which frankly is best represented as an Excel spreadsheet.  By this I mean:

- There are a lot of columns which need 'summing up'
- There is a reasonable amount of data (basically a sheet of numbers)

At the moment this is just raw data in a database, but I also have a spreadsheet which shows this data (along with formulas that I need to replicate in my app).

At the moment I've just got a `List<of T>` of each row, however I believe there might be a better collection for storing data of this type.  I basically need to be able to manipulate these numbers easily.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) which also has a [builtin aggregation method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx).

For example(from MSDN):

```
// Presumes a DataTable named "Orders" that has a column named "Total."
DataTable table;
table = dataSet.Tables["Orders"];

// Declare an object variable.
object sumObject;
sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Total)", "EmpID = 5");
```

Another advantage is that it supports LINQ queries with [LINQ-To-DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx).

Comment: I'm using LINQ to Entities to retrieve this data, hence getting into a DataTable can be a hassle

Comment: Then you should use LINQ-To-Entities to aggregate your data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716738.aspx#_LINQ2E

Answer (score 2):

If your "excel data" can be represented in models, I'd just use models. For example like so:

```
public class ExcelModel()
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public double value1 { get; set; }
     public int value1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can easily create a `List<ExcelModel>`, and get the total like so:

```
List<ExcelModel> model = repository.GetAll(); //just an example
var total = model.sum(x => x.value1);
```